# Smooth round over on large pieces of wood

Tags: technique

I'm thinking about building a country kitchen table. The link below is the design I'm considering for the frame.

What I'm trying to figure out is how the woodworker got those large round overs so perfect.

Also, I see an amazing lack of fasteners. I recognize that the 2x6 construction allows you to hide fasteners, but I do not see any in the cantilevered pieces either.

Wood putty or some tricky joinery?

[image]

https://pin.it/6m9rVk2

Comment: You can do those kinds of round corners any number of ways, they're actually not even that hard. In the past guides might have suggested only sawing off the corner, then going at it from both sides with a large chisel, but of course you'd have less cleanup to do if you used a turning saw. But these days, bandsaw + sanding is how 90%+ of people would probably do it. *"Also, I see an amazing lack of fasteners. I recognize that the 2x6 construction allows you to hide some but I fine see any in the cantilevered pieces either."* Joinery! You shouldn't see fasteners on nearly any formal furniture.

Comment: As you see, we have two answers and only one answers both questions. This is why you are encouraged to ask a single question at a time.

Comment: Sounds like a good way to pick the better answer to me.

Comment: Please see the fourth bullet point under **Answer well-asked questions** in [How do I write a good answer?](https://woodworking.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-answer). Question should be about one major topic, with *maybe* a directly related query tacked on but no more than that. Definitely not two unrelated queries, that leads to Q&As which are of lesser value in the future, which is directly counter to the way SE is set up to work — because the secondary query has nothing to do with the title, future searchers will have much greater difficulty in finding it. [contd]

Comment: Plus, there's no limit to the number of Questions you're allowed ask anyway. And you'll tend to get better, more focussed (and possibly much more fleshed out) Answers if you ask everything separately. Here for example the main thing you asked is barely touched on in the selected Answer, with more time spent on the secondary query! A better Answer would have given you a number of options on how the rounded corners were done, as I did in my Comment above ;-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- To get round ends on the bottom, use a band saw

  > Wood putty or some tricky joinery?

No wood putty needed or tricky joinery needed.
Some of my ideas on how to create the hidden connectors.

1. For the long span – Mortise/tenon – easy to do. The middle pieces are cripple from the top to the span board.  Another cripple from the bottom up to the span board.
2. The center post can be made of three pieces laminated together.  The two outer pieces use screws on the backside to fasten the 45^ brace
3. The top pieces are also laminated with either 2 or three layers.  On the bottom layer, use screws to connect to the angle brace before laminating the top pieces
   Picture from "furniturebypete":

[image]

You can go to this [woodworking projects sites](https://www.ana-white.com/woodworking-projects/fancy-x-farmhouse-bench) (and others) for free plans on how to build one similar to your design.

Comment: Please be careful about recommending that godawful site. It has done more to spread poor construction methods in recent years than anything! It's not that pocket screws are bad, far from it, but overuse of them isn't ideal and the plans there are infamous for using them incorrectly (taking zero account of wood movement).

Answer (score 2):

My guess would be a bandsaw and sandpaper to get those nice round overs. The invisible fasteners could be a number of things:

1. Mortise/tenon
2. wood glue
3. biscuit/domino/rod joinery

My guess would be a combination of all. I don't see screw holes nor wood filler, but they might just be that good.